# Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ of non-negative integers such that (i) $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots;$ and (ii) there exists

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ of non-negative integers such that
(i) $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots;$ and
(ii) there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n \ge N$.Define the dual of the sequence $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ belonging to $S$ to be the sequence $(b_1,b_2,\ldots)$, where, for $m\ge 1$, $b_m$ is the number of $a_n$'s which are greater than or equal to $m.$
$(ii)$ Show that the dual of the dual of a sequence in $S$ is the original sequence itself.

The solution for part (ii) and (iii) given is as follows:

> Define matrix $P$ such that $p_{ij}=1 \iff a_i \geq j$ otherwise $p_{ij}=0$.
> It is easy to show that sum of row $i$ of $P$ equals $b_i$, and sum of column $j$ of P equals $a_j$.
> Define a similar matrix $Q$ such that $Q_{ij}=1 \iff b_i \geq j$ otherwise $Q_{ij}=0$.
> Now the only thing that remains is to show $Q=P^T$.
> $$p_{ij}=1 \to a_i \geq j \to \text{at least i }a_i\geq j \to b_j \geq i \to q_{ji}=1 $$
> $$p_{ij}=0 \to a_i < j \to \text{less than i }a_i\geq j \to b_j < i \to q_{ji}=0 $$
> So
> $$p_{ij}=q_{ji}.$$ This completes the proof for part $(ii).$ For part *iii*,show that the corresponding matrices of two different sequences are different in at least one row.

I could solve part (i).However, I dont get that how are they stating that "It is easy to show that sum of row $i$ of $P$ equals $b_i$, and sum of column $j$ of P equals $a_j$." ? Also, in the part, where they claim "Define a similar matrix $Q$ such that $Q_{ij}=1 \iff b_i \geq j$ otherwise $Q_{ij}=0$.
Now the only thing that remains is to show $Q=P^T$." Why is it sufficient to prove, $Q=P^T$ for (ii) ? I dont get how to do the part (iii)...